# Blurry svg image in Android

Tags: java, android, svg, vector, android-xml

I added a user svg image from [this](https://materialdesignicons.com/) website. The image should be sharp, but when i use it in my app as a default user image it is very blurry.

```
<!-- Thumbnail Image -->
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
   android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
   android:background="@drawable/ic_icon_user"
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
```

Also how would I edit a svg image color in android. I tried adding a custom color, but it didn't work.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">
       <path
            android:fillColor="@color/ColorRed"
            android:pathData="M12,4A4,4 0 0,1 16,8A4,4 0 0,1 12,12A4,4 0 0,1 8,8A4,4 0 0,1 12,4M12,14C16.42,14 20,15.79 20,18V20H4V18C4,15.79 7.58,14 12,14Z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: For the color: try `android:fillColor="#ff0000"`

Comment: @Rotwang Thanks for your reply. I tried it but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Weird. That's an example from the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)

Comment: @Rotwang I know, weird. It might be something else... I will try and redo it from the beginning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding this to app `build.gradle` helped me to fix the problem with blurry svg images:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using API 21, so my app crashes, I will try to work around this when I find some free time, and let you know and hopefully accept your answer :) 

Thanks.

Comment: Changed my API to 24, added `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon_user"` instead of `android:background="@drawable/ic_icon_user"` and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Why does **useSupportLibrary** prevent SVG from being blurry?

Answer (score 1):

1. In Android Manifest.xml, set for your activity (blur doesn't work when hardware acceleration is true)

   ```
   android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
   ```
2. You can disable hardware acceleration
   on the VIEW level:

   ```
   myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Well similar problem happened to me. I was using

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_image".
```

Turns out this was causing the problem. You need to change it to this:

```
android:src="@drawable/your_image".
```